# Setting the C standard flag enables GNU extensions

Tags: gcc, cmake, c99, compiler-options

If I do:

```
 set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY C_STANDARD 99)
```

in a `CMakeLists.txt` and the C compiler is gcc, I get a `-std=gnu99` flag rather than `-std=c99`. Why? And how do I enforce a `-std=c99`?

Answer (score 3):

There is [C_EXTENSIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/C_EXTENSIONS.html#prop_tgt:C_EXTENSIONS) target property, which specifies whether compiler-specific extensions are requested:

> This property specifies whether compiler specific extensions should be used. For some compilers, this results in adding a flag such as `-std=gnu11` instead of -`std=c11` to the compile line. This property is `ON` by default. The basic C standard level is controlled by the `C_STANDARD` target property.

You may set this property to `OFF` for get "pure" C standard.